# Bootstrap: Dropdown as wide as the image

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I want to make a localisation dropdown with "flag images" under Laravel 5.4. I achieved it, but the dropdown is much wider than the images. How to configure it if I want to be the dropdown as wide as the images?

My snippet:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="/img/flags/{{App::getLocale()}}.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('lang/hu')}}"><img src="/img/flags/hu.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('lang/en')}}"><img src="/img/flags/en.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Update:**

[image: Localisation dropdown]

Comment: A screenshot could help.

Comment: @Spectarion I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.dropdown-menu` class has a `min-width`property. Override it with `min-width: 0` so it will be the same width as your flag icons.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="/img/flags/{{App::getLocale()}}.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:0">
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('lang/hu')}}"><img src="/img/flags/hu.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL::to('lang/en')}}"><img src="/img/flags/en.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Preview:

[image: Flags preview]

Note: If you don't want that space around flags, edit `padding` property.